# How to fix Google Play Store Update Error in Android 4.0.4?

Tags: google-play-store, notifications, system-error

I hope this question is not a duplicate of other related questions. In my Samsung Galaxy S duos mobile (Android 4.0.4 OS) I received frequent notification to update my software. Though I updated(Re-booted) it after receiving that notification I hate that notification so I disabled that. After disabling that when I tried to open Google Maps App its showing me an error “**Google Play Store Update Error**” and I was not able to open Map App as well as other Apps. I thought this error happens only because I disabled that software notification and I tried to enable that notification but I’m not able to enable that one.  So how to fix Google Play Store Update Error and how to enable that software notification?

Comment: It'll be easier to help you if you can give some more details: the **exact** text of all the messages, and what **exact** steps you took when you "updated(Re-booted)" the phone and disabled the notification.

Comment: It could be an issue with Google Play Services. Have you changed anything there? It's hard to tell what you changed, and what exactly is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Since this app is a Google native app which handles its own updates by itself, maybe the update went wrong. At the moment you could clear its cache, data (you will have to reenter the credentials later again and configure the playstore including notifications and update handling), or uninstall the updates, so it will go to the initial version (can be done by going in Settings -> Applications -> All -> Google Play Store). It should update later automatically.

In case you have a rooted phone, make sure you haven't done any changes in the system lately, or other apps are not interfering (any "freezers", "killers", or similar ones). Also, check if you haven't forbidden mobile network access (Settings -> Data usage, there you can click each app and check/uncheck "Restrict background data"), but even if this was checked, it should work on WiFi.